# Java drawing jerky animation

Tags: java, animation, drawing

I'm trying to do an animation but it's not fluid. I already had this problem before and I solved it by adding this line:
`System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true")`
which enable opengl but this time it doesn't work. So I looked at my FPS and it says that it turn at a stable 60 fps.
When I'm moving the mouse or taping on the keyboard the animation is fluid and it's also fluid when I do this:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, 3) //values doesn't matter
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null)
```

I added a start and a end variable to see how much time it takes to render and it's about 20 000 ns so 0.00002s per frame.

Here is my code:

Main class:

```
class Game() extends JFrame implements Runnable {

  GameScreen gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
  gameScreen.setLayout(null);
  Thread gameThread = new Thread(this, "GameLoop");

  int FPS_SET = 60.0;
  int UPS_SET = 10.0;

  Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.getScreenSize();

  this.setSize(dim.width, dim.height);
  this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setContentPane(gameScreen)
  this.setVisible(true);

  private void updateGame() {
    
    //function which change the current image of the animation
    updateAnimatedImage()

  }

  @Override
  public void run() {

    int timePerFrame = 1000000000.0 / FPS_SET;
    int timePerUpdate = 1000000000.0 / UPS_SET;

    int lastFrame = System.nanoTime;
    int lastUpdate = System.nanoTime;
    int lastTimeCheck = System.currentTimeMillis;

    int updates = 0;
    Long now = 0L;

    while (true) {

      now = System.nanoTime;

      // Render
      if (now - lastFrame >= timePerFrame) {
        repaint();
        lastFrame = now;
        frames += 1;
      }

      // Update
      if (now - lastUpdate >= timePerUpdate) {
        updateGame();
        lastUpdate = now;
        updates += 1;
      }
 
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeCheck >= 1000) {

        System.out.println("UPS: "+updates+", FPS: "+gameScreen.fps);
        updates=0;
        gameScreen.fps=0;
        lastTimeCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();

      }

        
    }

  }
```

Jpanel class:

```
class GameScreen() extends JPanel {

  int fps = 0;

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(g: Graphics) {

    int start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    super.paintComponent(g);

    //Makes the animation fluid
    //BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, 3)
    //g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null)

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    
    g2.drawImage(myImageAnimated.getImage(), 0, 0, null);   
       
    g2.dispose();￼

    int end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("render time: "+(end-start));

    this.fps++;

  }

}
```

myImageAnimate.getImage() doesn't give always the same image. This create the animation.

I'm on Linux, maybe it change somethings.

Comment: Won't solve your problem but don't update variables (ie. fps) in a painting method. You can't control when the painting method is called. The purpose of the paintComponent() method is to paint the current state of the class, not change the state. Also, not sure how you get animation. It looks to me like the image is always painted at (0, 0) and I don't see any logic where you update the image so the posted code doesn't really help.

Comment: I agree with camickr.  Also, your `run` method has no sleep in its `while` loop, so it’s taking up quite a lot of CPU time, and it’s repainting *very* frequently.  Also, remove `g2.dispose()`.  Do not dispose of a Graphics object unless you yourself created it.

Comment: @camickr yes sorry I forgot to say that the image isn't moving on screen but change with the update method